# Sending ARP reply with arbitrary source MAC

Tags: c, networking, arp

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [ARP reply packet does not update ARP cache on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896236/arp-reply-packet-does-not-update-arp-cache-on-ubuntu).  It turned out that my problem was that I was using an arbitrary MAC address as my source MAC (ie. one that doesn't exist on my network, say aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff).  I could send ARP replies to poison my cache with no problem *as long as my source MAC matches with the MAC of my NIC*.  I tried to manually set my NIC to have an arbitrary MAC address, then send ARP replies using that as my ARP packet's source MAC - also worked.

I am wondering if anybody knows the inner workings of this.  Was there some kind of check that prevents packets with mismatched source MAC from being sent?  Was it a check between the source MAC of the Ethernet frame vs. the source MAC of the ARP packet?  And for the purpose of an experiment that I'm running, is there a way to bypass this restriction?

JY

Answer (score 0):

> Various optimizations are possible to make ARP work more efficiently.
>   To start with, once a machine has run ARP, it caches the result in 
>   case it needs to contact the same machine shortly. Next time it will
>   find the mapping it its own cache, thus eliminating the need for a 
>   second broadcast. In many cases, host 2(receiver) will need to send 
>   back a reply, forcing it, too, to run ARP to determine the sender's 
>   Ethernet address. This ARP broadcast can be avoided by having sender 
>   include its IP-to-Ethernet mapping in the ARP packet.

Quoted from Tanenbaum's Computer Networks, fifth Edition p486-487

So it looks like your receiver fails to resolve MAC of the sender. And Tanenbaum presented a solution to you to avoid this failure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not sure if I understood correctly though, because I was under the impression that the receiver only replies if it gets an ARP **request**.  In my case, my sender is always sending ARP **replies** directly (ie. unsolicited ARP replies).  I am also a bit confused as to how I would include the sender's IP-to-Ethernet mapping in the ARP packet - wouldn't it just be the sender IP and sender MAC?  But the sender IP and MAC are what's controlling the spoofing, so they can't be altered?  I think I'm missing something very important here :P

Answer (score 0):

> Was there some kind of check that prevents packets with mismatched
>   source MAC from being sent? Was it a check between the source MAC of
>   the Ethernet frame vs. the source MAC of the ARP packet?

You mention Ubuntu. In Linux, you can send any Ethernet frame ([see](http://hacked10bits.blogspot.fi/2011/12/sending-raw-ethernet-frames-in-6-easy.html) [examples](https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600)), so internally there is no any kind of such check. But you did not tell how do you attempt to send the spoofed ARP messages; maybe the way **you** are doing it is limiting your options for the source MAC address.